# Checking if values in an array are within a range

Tags: java

I have 2 arrays. One is twice the size of the other. `array2` represents pairs of doubles, for example, `array2[0]` is a lower bound and `array2[1]` is the upper bound. I want to check if `array1[0]` is between the values `array2[0]` and `array2[1]`, if `array1[1]` is between values of `array2[2]` and `array2[3]` and so on. If this is the case for the entire array I want to return true, otherwise return false.

Here's what I have been trying so far but it does not work.

```
double[] array1 = new double[10];
double[] array2 = new double[20];

public boolean match(double[] array1, double[] array2) {
    boolean b = false;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] > array2[i * 2] && array1[i] < array2[i * 2 + 1]) {
            count++;  
        }
    }
    if (count == array1.length) {
        b = true; 
    }
    return b;
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by **doesn't work**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is incorrect:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] > array2[i * 2] && array1[i] < array2[i * 2 + 1]) {
        count++;  
    }
}
```

You check the index `i*2`, which will yield `8` when `i` is `4`. However you want to check at the index before and behind `i`. One way to do this is to keep track of what index you are on and use that to check the elements in `array2`:

```
public static boolean match(double[] array1, double[] array2) {
    boolean b = false;
    int index = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] > array2[index++] && array1[i] < array2[index++]) {
            count++;  
        }
    }
    if (count == array1.length) {
        b = true; 
    }
    return b;
}
```

Using the post increment operator we can up the counter every time we call the index, so that we will call the correct index of `array2`.

---

Also we can make this method more efficient by exiting as soon as the condition becomes false:

```
if (array1[i] <= array2[i * 2] || array1[i] >= array2[i * 2 + 1]) {
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was trying to do.